# Are these two python statements the same?

Tags: python, operators

I have these two statements

```
return self.getData() if self.getData() else ''
```

and

```
return self.getData() or ''
```

I want to know are they same or there is any difference

Comment: @Nabin I tried and it worked but i was not sure if that will cause any issue in some other cases which i don't know

Comment: The first may call the function twice.

Comment: @Nabin Just because something appears to work the same, does not actually mean they are the same. There is a subtle difference between the two statements that may not necessarily be apparent to everyone.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would say No because if `self.getData()` changes something during its operation, then the first statement has the possibility of returning a different result since it will make a 2nd call to it.

Comment: Ahh; this is what's known as "side effects" :)

Answer (score 22):

Maybe, but only if `self.getData()` is a pure function and has no *side effects*. More importantly the object that `self.getData()` returns must also be free of any side effects and consistently return a boolean value.

In the simplest case if `f()` is defined as:

```
def f():
    return ["Hello World!"]
```

Then the following:

```
x = f() if f() else ""
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
x = f() or ""
```

Since `f()` is treated as a boolean expression in both cases and `f()` will evaluate to a `True`(ish) or `False`(ly) value both expressions will return the same result.

This is called [Logical Equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)

> In logic, statements p and q are logically equivalent if they have the
>   same logical content. This is a semantic concept; two statements are
>   equivalent if they have the same truth value in every model (Mendelson
>   1979:56). The logical equivalence of p and q is sometimes expressed as
>   p \equiv q, Epq, or p \Leftrightarrow q. However, these symbols are
>   also used for material equivalence; the proper interpretation depends
>   on the context. Logical equivalence is different from material
>   equivalence, although the two concepts are closely related.

Comment: The things which getData can return is [data] or  `None` , `empty []` or False.  will that work same

Comment: @user3214546 Yes; as long as ``[data]`` is identical in subsequent calls to ``self.getData()``; e.g: a getter for a property called ``self._data``.

Comment: Nitpicking: Actually you need a stronger precondition that the one you listed. Also the `__bool__` method of the return value must be a pure method. It's possible that the `getData` function returns *the same object* but this object behaves as a true value the first time and as a false value the second time, independently on the operations inside `getData` (it could even just be: `return X`).

Comment: More nitpicking: accessing the `getData` property must also be free of side-effects.

Comment: small nitpick: `iff` is actually incorrect here, because for a non-pure function with side effects the answer is "maybe" and not "no" :)

Answer (score 8):

They will have the same result, since both treat `self.getData()`'s result in a boolean context, but beware:

1)
`return self.getData() if self.getData() else ''`

will run the function `getData` twice, while

2)
`return self.getData() or ''`

will only run it once. This can be important if `getData()` takes a while to execute, and it means that 1) is *not* the same as 2) if the function `getData()` has any side effects.

Stick with 2).

Comment: Anything that doesn't return in Python returns `None`, which is falsy. So it will be as if it returned `False`.

Answer (score 7):

The only difference I see is that the first one will call `self.getData()` twice, with the first one being used to evaluate boolean value and the second may be returned(if the first evaluated to True).

The other option will evaluate the function only once, using it both as boolean checking and returning.

This can be crucial if, for example, `self.getData()` deletes or modifies the data after returning it or the function takes long to compute.